# How to remove "Login Item" Mac 13.1 Ventura

Tags: login-items

I've read the other "How to remove login item" answers, and they don't apply here.
I get 9 warnings like this after a reboot:

[image]

I opened the Settings app (MacOS 13.1 Ventura), and found "Login Items" was an entry in "Privacy and Security" (it would be helpful to point that out, Apple Dumpling gang).  However, when I looked a second time, a few minutes later, the "Login Items" entry was gone!

How can I remove these items, and how were the companies able to add them in the first place?   What were they intended for?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list in Settings > General > Login Items, under "Allow in the Background".

They come from software that you have installed. You can turn them off with the switch there.

Some apps may use background processes for a variety of purposes, like checking for updates. It's just a non-windowed process that might periodically do something. Apple has made it seem a bit scary with the new interface and notifications, but it's nothing to worry about.

Presumably, you have installed, and are using, software from Citrix, HP, Oracle and Amazon?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer and explanation, Ben.    I haven't used Citrix for several years, and I have never used Amazon Mobile.   I'll yank the privilege on those.    Do you happen to know where I can find the associated executables to delete them?   Is there a folder somewhere containing items to run on restart?

Comment: @PetervdL They are usually in the Launch Agents or Launch Daemons subfolder of the root level /Library; or the same in the user ~/Library. Though they can also be inside an application's bundle, and maybe other places. Etrecheck will give you a detailed report, including filepaths.